# MySQL : Make HAVING select also "null"

Tags: mysql, select, group-by, having

I have two tables : `dilemme` and `like`. The first one contains articles and the second one contains votes. The script SELECT randomly one article to show and the user can vote (it's like and dislike).

I want to make a query that shows only the articles that have more than - 5 voting, the articles that has no vote are equal to 0.

So I tried this :

```
SELECT d.ph1, d.ph2, d.id, SUM(l.vote) AS score
FROM dilemme d
LEFT JOIN like l
ON d.id = l.id_dilemma
WHERE d.valid = 'yup'
GROUP BY d.id HAVING SUM(l.vote) > 0
```

It shows me correctly the rows that have at least one vote and that the sum of the votes are more than 0. Which is nice but, how to select also articles without vote ?

I tried a bunch of things and did some research but can't fix my problem.
I thought about INSERT INTO like a vote of 0 but I don't think its a good idea since it won't be very an optimized solution.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This should include either articles that have positive votes, or include articles with no votes by using `COUNT(l.id_delemma) = 0`

```
SELECT d.ph1, d.ph2, d.id, SUM(l.vote) AS score
FROM dilemme d
LEFT JOIN like l
ON d.id = l.id_dilemma
WHERE d.valid = 'yup'
GROUP BY d.id 
HAVING 
    SUM(l.vote) > 0
    OR COUNT(l.id_delemma) = 0
```

Comment: @RachidZuco You're welcome... that was an interesting one! First time I've used an `OR` in a `HAVING` clause I think.

Answer (score 3):

Use the ifnull function in your `select` and `having` clause:

```
...having(ifnull(l.vote,0)) > 0...
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT d.ph1, d.ph2, d.id, SUM(IFNULL(l.vote, 0)) AS score
FROM dilemme d
LEFT JOIN like l
ON d.id = l.id_dilemma
WHERE d.valid = 'yup'
GROUP BY d.id
HAVING score > 0
```

But I'm not sure how you expect this to work. If an item has no votes, how can its score be greater than 0?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The idea was nice. However this query won't give the expected result. As Alex Monthy mentioned is his answer, the ifnull has to go in the having clause.